# Multiple relations to same table with one required and others optional in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a table named `Provider` with three relations to another table `State`. Of these relations one is required and the other two are optional. See the relationship in the diagram below:

[image: multiple relationship]

Here are the entities along with the fluent configurations for each.

#### Provider

```
public class Provider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PrimaryStateId { get; set; }
    public virtual State PrimaryState { get; set; }

    public int? BillingStateId { get; set; }
    public virtual State BillingState { get; set; }

    public int? ShippingStateId { get; set; }
    public virtual State ShippingState { get; set; }
}

class ProviderConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Provider>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Provider> entity)
    {
        entity.HasOne(x => x.PrimaryState)
              .WithMany(x => x.ProvidersPrimary)
              .IsRequired(true)
              .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        entity.HasOne(x => x.BillingState)
              .WithMany(x => x.ProvidersBilling)
              .IsRequired(false)
              .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

        entity.HasOne(x => x.ShippingState)
              .WithMany(x => x.ProvidersShipping)
              .IsRequired(false)
              .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
    }
}
```

#### State

```
public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Provider> ProvidersPrimary { get; set; } = new List<Provider>();
    public virtual ICollection<Provider> ProvidersBilling { get; set; } = new List<Provider>();
    public virtual ICollection<Provider> ProvidersShipping { get; set; } = new List<Provider>();
}

class StateConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<State>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<State> entity)
    {
        entity.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();
        entity.HasIndex(x => x.Name).IsUnique();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to set `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` for the `PrimaryState`, and `DeleteBehavior.SetNull` for the other two relations. However, this throws error on `update-database` with the following message:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Provider_State_ShippingStateId' on table 'Provider' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

However, if I get rid of one of the optional relations, it works fine. That is, it works when I have one required relation and one optional relation, but not when I have one required and two optional relations. Also, it works fine if I get rid of `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)` from the optional relations, but then in the database the delete rule for foreign key `BillingStateId` ends up being `Set Null`, but that for `ShippingStateId` is `No Action`. No idea why it is different for two similarly configured optional relations.

Questions:

1. Why does `update-database` fail with that error? I don't understand how cycles or multiple cascade paths may be caused.
2. Why getting rid of `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)` creates a foreign key with `Set Null` delete rule for one optional relation but `No Action` for the other?
3. What is the correct way to configure this relationship? That is, one required relation and two optional relations, and the foreign keys for the optional relations should have a delete rule of `Set Null`.

VS Solution link: [click](https://github.com/suhailmahmood/MultipleForeignRelation)

Comment: Regarding #1, ask SqlServer dev team why is that limitation and why not willing to fix it for so many years.

Comment: @IvanStoev so you are saying it's a limitation of the SQL server itself, and not anything to do with EF Core? Is this documented somewhere? Thanks for the insight btw

Comment: Yes, that exception is definitely from SQL Server, not EF.

Comment: @IvanStoev Any suggestion as to how I can achieve what I want?

Comment: Use `DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull` and handle `State` deletion client side, e.g. load  with related data `var stateToDelete = db.Set<State>().Include(x => x.ProvidersBilling).Include(x => x.ProvidersShipping).FirstOrDefault(...);` and then delete `db.Remove(stateToDelete);`

Comment: @IvanStoev That's not what I want. State should definitely not be deleted on deleting Provider. I want to set the foreign keys to null when State is deleted. As I said, getting rid of the `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)` from the optional relations does the job, but I had a question about that too..

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ I'm talking about deleting `State` object/record, not `Provider`. Since database cannot handle that with `SetNull` action, let EF Core handle it with client code (`ClientSetNull` action).